# How to display a counter formated like that YY MM DD HH

Tags: dart

Hello I have a counter who works perfectly formatted like DD HH mm ss but I don't successed to transform in YY MM DD HH

Here is the working format

```
      var  _lastConso = lastConsoString!=null ? DateTime.parse(lastConsoString) : DateTime.now();
      var  duration_conso = DateTime.now().difference(_lastConso);
      final newDuration =_formatDuration_conso(duration_conso);
      String _finalDuration_conso = newDuration; //_finalDuration_conso is the string I use to display counter
```

---

```
String _formatDuration_conso(Duration duration) {
    String twoDigits(int n) {
      if (n >= 10) return "$n";
      return "0$n";
    }

    String twoDigitHours = twoDigits(duration.inHours.remainder(24));
    String twoDigitMinutes = twoDigits(duration.inMinutes.remainder(60));
    String twoDigitSeconds = twoDigits(duration.inSeconds.remainder(60));
    return "${twoDigits(duration.inDays)}   $twoDigitHours   $twoDigitMinutes   $twoDigitSeconds";
  }
```

Here is the example of enzo

```
String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
  // Create some constants we'll use during the calculation
  const int hoursPerDay = Duration.hoursPerDay;
  const int hoursPerYear = hoursPerDay * 365;
  const int hoursPerMonth = hoursPerDay * 30;
  
  // Calculate the number of years based on the number of the total
  // hours and deduct the number of years from the total hours
  final int years = duration.inHours ~/ hoursPerYear;
  int remainder = duration.inHours % hoursPerYear;
  
  // Do the same for months and days until reach the remaning hours
  final int months = remainder ~/ hoursPerMonth;
  remainder %= hoursPerMonth;
  
  final int days = remainder ~/ hoursPerDay;
  remainder %= hoursPerDay;
  
  final int hours = remainder;

  return [years, months, days, hours]
      // An alternative for your `twoDigit` method: Transform the
      // value into a string and add a zero to it if the length of
      // the string (i.e. number of digits) is lesser than 2
      .map((v) => "$v".padLeft(2, "0"))
      // Join all the values delimited by a space
      .join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What errors are you running into? Include logs and stacktraces if applicable.

Comment: just duration.inYears and duration.inMouth doesn't exist, I write like this beceaus it's what I seach to have but it's impossible to do like this. But I don't know how to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `duration.inYears` or `duration.inMonth` properties, so you'll have to calculate it by yourself:

```
String formatDuration(Duration duration) {
  // Create some constants we'll use during the calculation
  const int hoursPerDay = Duration.hoursPerDay;
  const int hoursPerYear = hoursPerDay * 365;
  const int hoursPerMonth = hoursPerDay * 30;
  
  // Calculate the number of years based on the number of the total
  // hours and deduct the number of years from the total hours
  final int years = duration.inHours ~/ hoursPerYear;
  int remainder = duration.inHours % hoursPerYear;
  
  // Do the same for months and days until reach the remaning hours
  final int months = remainder ~/ hoursPerMonth;
  remainder %= hoursPerMonth;
  
  final int days = remainder ~/ hoursPerDay;
  remainder %= hoursPerDay;
  
  final int hours = remainder;

  // An alternative for your `twoDigit` method: Transform the
  // value into a string and add a zero to it if the length of
  // the string (i.e. number of digits) is lesser than 2
  // Finally, join all the values delimited by a space
  return [years, months, days, hours].map((v) => "$v".padLeft(2, "0")).join(" ");
}
```

Usage example:

```dart
print(formatDuration(Duration(days: 500, minutes: 1200)));
// Outputs 01 04 15 20
```

Note that this code assumes that every month contains 30 days, so it depends on your use case.

---

You may argue that you could calculate it as

```
final int years = duration.inDays ~/ 365;
final int months = duration.inDays ~/ 30;
final int days = duration.inDays;
final int hours = duration.inHours;
```

If you do so, the output will be `01 16 500 12020` (1 year, 16 months, 500 days and 12020 hours) instead of `01 04 15 20` (1 year, 4 months, 15 days and 20 hours), so again it depends on your use case.

Comment: thank you so much, it seems to print the correct counter, but I have a problem of compatibility, in this exemple in print well, but in output I have nothing display, I don't successed to have the same format like    
 return "$twoDigityears    $twoDigitmonth    $twoDigitdays"   $twoDigithours";

Comment: Sorry, I’m afraid I don’t follow you - do you want to return a formatted string instead of building a list and then joining it?

Comment: Yes I don't successed to return a string instead of list, I add specific space between each pair of digit to match with text below

Comment: Try replacing `.join(" ")` with `.join("   ")` (three spaces instead of one).

Comment: Note that I'm not returning the list `[years, months, days, hours]`. There's a `map` after the comments below it and there's also a `join`, which will join the elements of the list into a single string. I've edited my answer to make it more clear. If you have any question, feel free to ask!

Comment: Yeaj it's ok with .join("   ") I can manage my output. thank you for all, it's perfect !